# Calculate the maximum number of nodes a B-tree with arity m and n items can have

Tags: tree, computer-science, b-tree

I'm trying to calculate the exact number of nodes in the most wasteful B-tree you can have given arity `m` (maximum number of children per node) and `n` items in the tree. By most wasteful I mean the nodes in the tree contain the minimum amount of items possible.

Since the amount is to be exact, there are certain caveats. The root can have just 1 item, but this is impossible for certain values of `n` and the root would have to have more than 1 item. The non-root-non-leaf nodes would have an exact minimum number of `ceil((m-1)/2)` items. The leaves can have the same minimum but this is impossible for certain values of `n` and some leaf nodes would have to have more than `ceil((m-1)/2)` items. So this isn't just a trivial `log(n)/log(ceil((m-1)/2))`.

Is there a known way to calculate this?

Comment: @trincot yes you're right, I'll edit.

Comment: To clarify - are you asking about which B-tree could be arrived at through a standard series of insertions and deletions that has the most nodes, or the tree shape that meets the B-tree requirements and has the most nodes?